# Using sys.fn_IsBitSetInBitmask in SQL Azure

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure

Is there some special syntax for using `sys.fn_IsBitSetInBitmask()` in SQL Azure? I get the message

> Cannot find either column "sys" or the user-defined function or aggregate "sys.fn_IsBitSetInBitmask", or the name is ambiguous.

Normal "not supported" errors i'm used to, but the fact that this says "name is ambiguous" makes me think maybe there is something wrong with the way I'm calling it? There doesn't seem to be any documentation online saying its not supported, and it's not mentioned on any of the T-SQL differences pages I've checked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the same message you get for any function that doesn't exist, e.g. `SELECT dbo.what();`. This function is undocumented and unsupported, so you shouldn't be relying on it. There isn't really any way for Microsoft to document that something that is undocumented and unsupported is even more undocumented and unsupported in Azure.

Comment: Thanks! Documenting an undocumented feature does make little sense. Now to find an alternative...

Comment: For anyone else with issue, we just recreated this function in Azure. (EXEC sp_helptext 'fn_IsBitSetInBitmask')